# Can't generate issue to GitHub on ios app

Tags: swift, express, octokit

I made an express server which generates issue to GitHub with Octokit. This worked if it is on localhost but doesn't work if it is deployed by Vercel.

Express Server

```
const express = require("express");
var app = express();
const octo = require("octokit");
const Octokit = octo.Octokit;
require("dotenv").config();
const octokit = new Octokit({
    auth: process.env.GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN,
});
async function addIssue(title, description) {
    await octokit.request("POST /repos/Jonathan0827/WonsinheungMid/issues", {
        owner: "OWNER",
        repo: "REPO",
        title: title,
        body: title,
        labels: ["bug"],
        headers: {
            "X-GitHub-Api-Version": "2022-11-28",
        },
    });
    console.log("success");
}

app.post("/report", function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.query);
    addIssue(req.query.title, req.query.desc);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

iOS App

```
struct params: Encodable {
    let title: String
    let desc: String
}
func generateIssue(title: String, description: String) {
    let issue = params(title: title, desc: description)
    AF.request("URL",
               method: .post,
               parameters: issue,
               encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default).response { response in
        debugPrint(response)
    }
}
```